# Hadoop MapReduce: How to ensure multiple tasks are executed in parallel among all nodes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a task list file in HDFS and the list of tasks are CPU-bound and are to be executed in a small 5-node cluster with Hadoop MapReduce (Map only). For instance, the task list file contains 10 lines, each of which corresponds to a task command. The execution of each task takes way long time, so it is definitely more efficient to execute the listed 10 tasks in parallel on all the 5 nodes.

However, as the task list file is pretty small, this data block is probably located only on one node so that only that node will execute all these 10 tasks based on the data locality principle. Is there any solution to ensure that all the 10 tasks are executed in parallel on all the 5 nodes?

Comment: Depending if you would like to execute something else on the cluster, very easy, but with some drawbacks solution could be limiting the number of mappers per node (mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum configuration)

Answer (score 1):

By default, map reduce will run one mapper per split. A split is a block, so if you have a really large file, you will get one mapper per block size of the file (default is 128MB) which will process that 128MB chunk in parallel with the other chunks.

In your case, you have a series of lines in a very small file - this is only 1 split, and therefore it will be processed by a single mapper.

However, instead of having one file of 10 lines, can you create 10 files of one line? Then you will have 10 splits, and map reduce will run 10 mappers across the cluster in parallel (depending on available resources) to process your tasks.